# Will the src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')?>... work when hosting the page on the server?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am creating a template in wordpress in local environment and I have added several javascript files as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')?>/js-child/myFile.js"></script>
```

In local it works correctly but I don't know if it is adequate.
Could you give me problems when hosting the website on the server?

Comment: Why would it not work on the server if it works locally? As long as the `bloginfo` function exists and `echo`s the correct path, it should work

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a standard function and acceptable value, will work

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/